# Spring Webflow: No actions were executed

Tags: spring-webflow

I'm trying to implement an Action in SWF but I get the same error even in the simplest example.

Error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: No actions were executed, thus I cannot execute any state transition"

```
import org.springframework.webflow.execution.Action;
import org.springframework.webflow.execution.Event;
import org.springframework.webflow.execution.RequestContext;

public class HelloAction implements Action {
@Override
public Event execute(RequestContext rc) throws Exception {                
    return new Event(this, "success");
}
```

I've declared the bean.

```
 <bean id="helloAction" class="app.action.HelloAction"/>
```

And in flow.xml..

```
<action-state id="intermedio">
   <action bean="helloAction"/>
   <transition on="success" to="fin"/>
</action-state>

<end-state id="fin" view="final" />
```

**It works fine if I don't use "HelloAction"**. But if I want to use Action in SWF, I always get the previous error.

Is something else needed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<action-state id="intermedio">
    <evaluate expression="helloAction.execute()">
    <transition on="success" to="fin"/>
</action-state>
```

Comment: If I use that option, I obtain: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'evaluate'. 
I have also tried: 
<evaluate-action expression="helloAction.execute()"/>

Comment: Oh, wow. You're back on Spring Web Flow 1.0. Any particular reason why? (My example is 2.x)

Comment: In theory, my example is 2.x too. I'm using libraries 2.x

Comment: The error you're describing with this approach and the `evaluate-action` element point to you not referencing the 2.0 schema. Are you doing that?

Comment: Ok! You're right.
If I make reference to 2.0 schema, I can't use `<action>` element. For that reason, I changed my reference to 1.0. When I tried to use `<evaluate expression>` element, I forgot to change it again.
It works perfectly with: `<evaluate expression="helloAction"/>` (without .execute()). 

Thanks a lot!!