# Spring Webflow + Spring MVC: Action Bean in Java Annotation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, action, spring-webflow-2

I'm using Spring MVC + Spring Webflow 2.

I would like to define a @Bean for an action-state, but i don't know how to do this in Java Annotation, as i get this error:

> Method call: Method execute() cannot be found on
>   com.myapp.action.GaraAgenziaAction type

here an example of what i want to do: [spring-webflow-no-actions-were-executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575717/spring-webflow-no-actions-were-executed)

My Bean:

```
import org.springframework.webflow.execution.Action;
import org.springframework.webflow.execution.Event;
import org.springframework.webflow.execution.RequestContext;

public class GaraAgenziaAction implements Action {

    @Override
    public Event execute(RequestContext rc) throws Exception {                
        return new Event(this, "success");
    }
}
```

Flow XML:

```
<transition on="fail" to="gara-agenzie"/>

<transition on="success" to="gara-conferma"/>
```

My webAppConfig:

```
@Bean
public Action GaraAgenziaAction()
{
    GaraAgenziaAction garaAgenziaAction = new GaraAgenziaAction();

    return garaAgenziaAction;

}
```

Thank you very much

**UPDATE resolved thanks to @Prasad suggestions:**

My Bean (added @Component):

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.webflow.execution.Action;
import org.springframework.webflow.execution.Event;
import org.springframework.webflow.execution.RequestContext;

@Component
public class GaraAgenziaAction implements Action {

    @Override
    public Event execute(RequestContext rc) throws Exception {                
        return new Event(this, "success");
    }
}
```

My webAppConfig (changed name of the bean with lowercase):

```
@Bean
public Action garaAgenziaAction()
{
    GaraAgenziaAction beanAction = new GaraAgenziaAction();

    return beanAction;

}
```

Flow XMl configuration (changed bean name to lowercase and pass **flowRequestContext** as parameter):

```
<action-state id="action-agenzie">
    <evaluate expression="garaAgenziaAction.execute(flowRequestContext)"></evaluate>        

    <transition on="fail" to="gara-agenzie"/>

    <transition on="success" to="gara-conferma"/>
</action-state>
```

Now it's working fine!

Comment: Just define GaraAgenziaAction bean in 1) xml bean definitions file if xml is used or 2) use Component annotation on the action and call this in action-state. Also did you observe, you are using same class name for the one implementing interface and the one with Bean annotation?

Comment: Check the example mentioned in this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342621/web-flow-add-model-attribute-for-binding-with-form-values/23344985#23344985, which mostly covers the configuration and access the methods in ClassForThisFlow class in action-state(for SWF 1)/evaluate-action(for SWF 2 and later). Though ClassForThisFlow does not implement action. You can define any method in ClassForThisFlow and access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the action class in your servlet xml file as:

```
    <!--Class which handles the flow related actions-->
    <bean id="garaAgenziaAction" class=" com.myapp.action.GaraAgenziaAction">
    </bean>
```

or annotate it with Component as:

```
    @Component
    public class GaraAgenziaAction implements Action{
            @Override
            public Event execute(RequestContext rc) throws Exception {                
            return new Event(this, "success");
            }
    }
```

In your flow xml access it as:

```
    <action-state id="action-agenzie">
        <evaluate expression="garaAgenziaAction.execute(flowRequestContext)"></evaluate>
        <transition on="fail" to="gara-agenzie"/>
        <transition on="success" to="gara-conferma"/>
    </action-state>
```

For configuration details you can find it in the answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342621/web-flow-add-model-attribute-for-binding-with-form-values/23344985#23344985).